# Movie of a family living inside a bubble, humans outside pelting ice cubes at the bubble to try and break the bubble-like-barrier

Tags: story-identification, movie

The family seemed to be from the past or Amish. They went about doing daily chores but I think when the bubble was broken, they became violent.

The people on the outside seemed to be studying them and were pelting ice cubes at the barrier using some sort of a tennis-ball-dispensing machine.

The whole point of the movie seemed to be to break the barrier but it had a sense of mystery and horror as well.

I watched this movie when I was around 10 (so ~2002) but the movie was airing on television.

Comment: @drewbenn That's it!! Thanks!

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/short-story-army-investigates-barrier-and-house?noredirect=1&lq=1 (about the short story on which the video was based)