# Live-action sci-fi show or movie where soldiers discover a portal to an ideal universe that looks Victorian

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

The only thing I can remember is that soldiers have discovered a portal that they can see through, but not pass through. On the other side is an ideal universe that looks Victorian. They are using a machine to launch ice cubes at the portal to find when the wall will be down.

One soldier thinks it's a perfect world and wants in. When he notices the ice cubes pass the invisible wall he jumps through. Walking up to the women he's seen, he greets them. They then attack and begin to eat him. The soldiers back in our world watch in horror. An old man walking up a path says some words and the portal closes. The stinger is that he reversed the portal and is now testing for when they can pass through.

I'd like to know what show or movie this is from. I can't remember.

Comment: @Otis - I could be mistaken -- and I'm sure someone will correct me if I am -- but I'm under the impression that a question should only be closed as a duplicate if it's asking about the same story in the same medium. Since this question is asking about a TV episode, and the one you linked to is asking about the original short story, I don't think a dupe closure applies here. As I said, if I'm wrong, I'm sure someone will correct me, but I have the distinct impression that I've seen this specific situation discussed before.

Comment: Well, the answer regarding the TV episode has been accepted, so voting to close.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant. - Yes, but I've searched the site archives, and this is currently the only question which has asked about the TV episode specifically, rather than the short story. The TV episode is based on the short story, but it's an adaptation in a different medium, which means it's not exactly the same. The title of the episode is also different from the short story, so while they're clearly related, they're not one and the same.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant. - I've reopened the thread, but [I've also asked the mods for clarification on this point](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60975169#60975169) one way or the other, so the final say on this will be down to them.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant. - Rand al'Thor directed me to a meta thread [in which this scenario was discussed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10051/what-constitutes-the-same-answer-for-story-identification-questions) to some extent, and it turns out that no real consensus was reached on the matter. So I guess that means it's down to us users to settle this amongst ourselves.

Comment: I've given some thought as to whether I should reclose the question myself or not, to reflect the fact that more users voted to close it than to leave it open. However, I did earn the privilege that enabled me to reopen this question, and I apparently wasn't strictly wrong to do so (though not strictly right, either, this being a grey area and all). So until or unless we receive clearer guidance from the mods on this, I've decided to leave it open for now. But if it ends up being flagged and closed again, I won't reopen it a second time.

Comment: @LogicDictates, I'm actually inclined to agree with you regarding same story but different medium counting as the basis for different duplicate groups, but see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197668/movie-of-a-family-living-inside-a-bubble-humans-outside-pelting-ice-cubes-at-th which had already been closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like the *[Night Visions](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0247120/)* episode, **"[A View Through the Window](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0660986/)"** (2001).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Visions_(TV_series)#Episodes):

> *Night Visions* is an American television horror anthology series, with each episode comprising two half-hour stories dealing with themes of the supernatural or simply the dark side of human nature. It was produced by Warner Bros. Television for the Fox network, originally airing from 2001 to 2002. Musician Henry Rollins was the uncredited host of the show.

From IMDB:

> In "A View Through the Window", Major Ben Darnell is a brilliant physicist and a grieving father, whose estranged wife blames him for the tragic accidental death of their little son. He's called up to a top secret location, where the military is investigating a strange supernatural phenomenon. **A portal to another place has somehow appeared in the middle of the desert and an invisible barrier is blocking it. The soldiers can see the people on the other side - a seemingly happy pilgrimesque family that's living in a picturesque farmhouse surrounded by a luscious green field, but the family can't see the portal or what's on the other side, so they're living their idyllic everyday life like normal.** Darnell is stricken by them, since they represent everything he wishes for in his tragic life. He eventually realizes that the barrier disappears for a few seconds each day and decides to risk everything to cross over to the other side despite his commanding officer's direct order not to try anything until they learn more about these people and their world.

You can view the scene with the ice cubes at around the [9:37](https://youtu.be/7aAY57plRYQ?t=577) mark in the video below. You can view the scene where one of the soldiers goes through the portal and is attacked by the people on the other side at around the [18:15](https://youtu.be/7aAY57plRYQ?t=1095) mark.

As per [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33706/122024), this story was apparently based on a 1980 short story by Bob Leman,  titled "[Window](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49702)".

Comment: Damn you're good! Thank you!