# Horror short story about a man looking into another world of always happy people. He eventually enters, and they rush him and eat him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

It's a short story, by a very well-known but not recent horror writer. It's at least 25 years since I read it, and it wasn't new then.

It was about a man, perhaps a scientist, who discovered a portal to a new world. For some reason I feel it was in a tree/forest but I'm not definite. He watches the people for some time, they are always happy and content. When he eventually steps through, they rush towards him, and he sees their wide smiles are full of long sharp teeth, as they fall on him.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short Story: Army investigates barrier and house](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/short-story-army-investigates-barrier-and-house)

Comment: @A.Steer - [meta consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065) is that we require _both_ questions to have an accepted answer before closing as a dupe

Answer (score 22):

This is probably "[Window](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49702)" (1980) by Bob Leman, first published in *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction*.

From the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_(short_story)) on Wikipedia:

> A researcher seeking to merge science and magic opens a “window” which reveals what seems to be a tranquil Victorian home and family. The viewpoint characters can see through the "window" to the family, but the family can't see them. Yearning for the apparently idyllic life seen through the portal, a man crosses to the other dimension but is immediately killed and eaten by the family. The family performs a ritual, closing the portal, and all disappear. However, the dead man's bones come out of thin air where the portal had been. The viewpoint characters realize that the man-eating family have found a "window" into their world and are now watching them.

Comment: Summary of all the times this has been asked about here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/251459/28516 The "master question" is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/short-story-army-investigates-barrier-and-house

Comment: This has been adapted for tv for the old series "Night Visions".